# why sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps works different in different kernel on container

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, linux-namespaces

I upgraded a machine's kernel from `3.10.0` to `4.20.13` and left else unchanged, but `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps` acts different on docker after upgrading as showed in below picture.

I am guessing this parameter become namespaced in new kernel but I can't find any evidence to prove my guess, can anybody give some advice, very thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it's introduced in this commit [tcp: Namespaceify sysctl_tcp_timestamps](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5d2ed0521ac98f1ae0243fe52b8ebf95e2abf791), and released in [kernel version 4.13](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.13),  just between 3.10 and 4.20.